# OIDC Client LoginAsync in Xamarin App iOS never returns result

Tags: xamarin.forms, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a Xamarin iOS application I am building. For the Authentication and Authorization I am using Identity Server. To logon I am using IdentityModel.OidcClient using version 4.0.0.

When a user click on a Login button I call the Identity Server using:

`_result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());`

I am redirected to my identity server and can succesfully login. After login the browser disappears but the code never reaches the next line:

```
_result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());

if (_result.IsError)
{
    return;
}
```

I have found many example and they all tell me to do the following. I have also tried with the demo Identity Server and same issue.

This is the IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser.IBrowser implementation:

```
public class ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser : IBrowser
    {
        ASWebAuthenticationSession _asWebAuthenticationSession;

        public ASWebAuthenticationSessionBrowser()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ctor");
        }

        public Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BrowserResult>();

            try
            {
                _asWebAuthenticationSession = new ASWebAuthenticationSession(
                    new NSUrl(options.StartUrl),
                    new NSUrl(options.EndUrl).Scheme,
                    (callbackUrl, error) =>
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult(CreateBrowserResult(callbackUrl, error));
                        _asWebAuthenticationSession.Dispose();
                    });

                // iOS 13 requires the PresentationContextProvider set
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
                    _asWebAuthenticationSession.PresentationContextProvider = new PresentationContextProviderToSharedKeyWindow();

                _asWebAuthenticationSession.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        class PresentationContextProviderToSharedKeyWindow : NSObject, IASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding
        {
            public UIWindow GetPresentationAnchor(ASWebAuthenticationSession session)
            {
                return UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            }
        }

        private static BrowserResult CreateBrowserResult(NSUrl callbackUrl, NSError error)
        {
            if (error == null)
                return new BrowserResult
                {
                    ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                    Response = callbackUrl.AbsoluteString
                };

            if (error.Code == (long)ASWebAuthenticationSessionErrorCode.CanceledLogin)
                return new BrowserResult
                {
                    ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel,
                    Error = error.ToString()
                };

            return new BrowserResult
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = error.ToString()
            };
        }

    }
```

I am using Xamarin.Forms and netstandard 2.0.

My redirect uri: RedirectUri = "wodtracker.app://callback"
[image]

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization

Comment: That seems to work, but than you do not have the browser with toolbar etc.